# C - Reading Cooked input from stream

Tags: c, input, fgets, termios

I know that there are many questions that are about "reading input" but to clarify I am trying to read cooked input. For some reason fgets is not cooked (Not sure if thats by default or I need to turn it on using termios) So any help? ncurses is not an option.

example: input hey then back space, it comes out as hey^H which is indicative of raw input mode

BTW I tried turning on canononical mode via termios and I'm still having trouble getting cooked input.

Comment: The shell isn't involved when a program is running.

Comment: Mk then, it has to work regardless of the shell being used.

Comment: line by line retrieval of input from the user where the user is capable of editing (IE Delete backspace arrow keys)

Comment: does one need to trace all the keys pressed during program being executed?

Comment: Cooked mode is normally the default. However, the erase/kill characters may not be set as you expect, check that.

Comment: @SparKot It's not needed but it wouldn't be hard to

Comment: @Barmar I'll check that out now.

Comment: check ioctl() as well to use raw mode.

Comment: termios is the struct used for wrappers with ioctl. And I wouldn't want to make it raw because that disables delimiters by newline, as well as processing.

Comment: @Barmar The Special character values are all set to default

Comment: The default erase character may be DEL (ASCII 127), but your backspace key is sending BS (ASCII 8).

Comment: That is true.And Delete does work but arrow key navigation does not work. Which I don't think can be achieved by this method. I'd have to use ncurses to acheive that right?